# Reloading AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift

In the AppDelegate I have the app colors:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let switchState = defaults.integer(forKey: "switchState")
    if switchState == 1 {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.black
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white]
        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.black
        UISearchBar.appearance().barStyle = UIBarStyle.black
        UITextField.appearance().keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearance.dark
    }
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

So that a slider turns on the "dark mode". But for changes to take effect, the app must be restarted. How can I do this without restarting the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply move your color logic to a function and then call that function when required.

So, you make a function like this in your class:

```
static func setColorsOfApp()
{
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let switchState = defaults.integer(forKey: "switchState")
    if switchState == 1 {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.black
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white]
        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.black
        UISearchBar.appearance().barStyle = UIBarStyle.black
        UITextField.appearance().keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearance.dark
    }
}
```

And then call this function like:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    YOUR_CALASS_NAME.setColorsOfApp()
    return true
}
```

and anywhere else you want.

Comment: I want the slider once it is turned on to immediately change the UI to dark.

Answer (score 0):

A cursory look through the documentation for `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` would reveal that that function is explicitly run once at launch. Have you considered moving this code out that function and into some other method that can be invoked more freely?

Google for how `UISwitch` work, and invoke Ayush's function from the callback so that your app will "immediately change the UI to dark"

Comment: Yes, I know what `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` does, right now when the slider is on, an UIAlertController shows, that asks the user to restart the app.